# How to handle null value in sqlite prepared statement

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, where-clause, sql-null

Consider a database, which models a directory tree and each file or folder is a record:

```
CREATE TABLE "tree" (
"id"    integer,
"parent_id" integer,
"name"  varchar(255),
UNIQUE("parent_id","name"),
PRIMARY KEY("id"),
FOREIGN KEY("parent_id") REFERENCES "tree"("id") on delete cascade
);
```

The node at root has parent_id set to NULL, since it has no parent.
In order to optimize runtime, I want to create a prepared statement to query the tree:

```
select * from tree where name=? and parent_id=?
```

The problem is that with the above statement even if I call sqlite3_bind_null, the select statement will not find the rows with parent_id NULL. It only works with the argument `parent_id is null`.

Currently is prepared two statements: one for NULL and one for != NULL, but that is not very elegant.
Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `null`-safe equality. In SQLite, you can use `is`:

```
select * 
from tree 
where name = ? and parent_id is ?
```

How this works is [explained in the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isisnot):

> The `IS` and `IS NOT` operators work like `=` and `!=` except when one or both of the operands are `NULL`. In this case, if both operands are `NULL`, then the `IS` operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the `IS NOT` operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is `NULL` and the other is not, then the `IS` operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the `IS NOT` operator is 1 (true).

Comment: Indeed it works! But unfortunately, it is approx. 2.5x slower now. (btw. I did not downvote, I find it useful).

Comment: @MiB_Coder: I guess that's the price to pay for the null-safety feature... An index on `(name, parent_id)` or (`parent_id, name)` may help the query.